# Spring roo horizontal menu

Tags: menu, menuitem, spring-roo

Is there a way I can change the vertical menu in a spring roo application to a vertical menu? I have worked in appfuse earlier, I think the velocity templates lets us change it..Is there something like that in roo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and of course you can.

Please feel free to modify the stylesheets and menu related files included in your generated Roo project.

Take a look at `menu.tagx` file to see how the default Spring MVC menu is created.